# Product minim amount multiply by 7 in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to put on my order at final when the user is on the cart and want at finish to verify the min amount. Need to be multiply of 7.

For example.. I have 20 products on shop. The min products amount is multiply of 7 of any product.

```
Ex:
Product with ID:3 & Quantity: 5
Product with ID:13 & Quantity: 2 
   => Total:7 = > Success

Product with ID:2 & Quantity: 3
Product with ID:6 & Quantity: 8
  => Total: 11 => Fail

Product with ID:1 & Quantity: 2
Product with ID:5 & Quantity: 8
Product with ID:11 & Quantity: 4
  => Total: 14 => Success
```

How can I do that? Here is what i've tried

```
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $minimum = 7;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() %  $minimum != 0) {
        $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order.' , $minimum ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

> You need to hook your function into
>   [`woocommerce_checkout_process`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_checkout_process/), to do your calculation and
>   display the error.

Something like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_wc_minimum_order_amount');

function wh_wc_minimum_order_amount()
{
    $minimum = 7;
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() % $minimum != 0)
    {
//      wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order.', $minimum), 'error');
    }
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! It's good, but I want to make this work when the user is clicking the button 'Place order'...when the user place the order...

Comment: @Hateres1990: I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: I saw it works, but i needed this version. Thanks my friend:)